# Join 2 Temp tables laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have following temp tables I wanna join them In query builder but I am failing to do so. I wanna join these 2 tables so I can do `i1.imp/i2.imp`

```
        $subQuery1 = MyModel::query()
            ->from("table as i1")
            ->select(
                \DB::raw('sum(col) as col1'),
                \DB::raw('co1')
            )->where('stamp', '>=', '2022-03-01 14:25:00')
            ->where('stamp', '<', '2022-03-07 14:30:00')
            ->groupBy(
                'co1'
            );
        $subQuery2 = MyModel::query()
            ->from("table as i2")
            ->select(
                \DB::raw('sum(col) as col1'),
                \DB::raw('co1')
            )->where('stamp', '>=', '2022-03-01 14:20:00')
            ->where('stamp', '<', '2022-03-07 14:25:00')
            ->groupBy(
                'co1'
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `from`, `fromSub` or `table` and pass in a subquery instead of a table.

You can do the same with `joinSub` for joins.

You need to provide an alias though.

For example, to use `$subquery1` as the main table and join it with `$subquery2`, the resulting query could look like this:

```php
$results = DB::query()
    ->select(.....)
    ->fromSub($subquery1, 'i1')
    ->joinSub($subquery2, 'i2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('i1.col', '=', 'i2.col');
             // ->orOn(....)
    });
    ->where(....)
    ->get();
```

- [Laravel 9.x API - `fromSub`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub)
- [Queries - Subquery Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#subquery-joins)

Comment: let me try please

Comment: I tried following
`$results = DB::query()->select('i1.col') ->fromSub($subQuery1, 'i1')->joinSub($subQuery2, 'i2', function ($join) {$join->on('i1.site_id', '=', 'i2.site_id');})->get();`
I am getting invalid arguments

Comment: If you replace `get()` with `toSql()` do you get the expected query?